# AWS memcached store always returns false

Tags: c#, asp.net, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I have below settings in webconfig

```
 <sectionGroup name="enyim.com">
      <!-- Memcached -->
      <section name="memcached" type="Enyim.Caching.Configuration.MemcachedClientSection,Enyim.Caching" />
    </sectionGroup>

<enyim.com>
    <memcached protocol="Binary">
      <servers>
        <add address="endpoint" port="15651"></add>
      </servers>
    </memcached>
  </enyim.com>
```

Below code

```
var mc = new MemcachedClient();
                var stat = mc.Store(StoreMode.Set, "Hello", "World");
```

Always false

```
MemcachedClientConfiguration config = new MemcachedClientConfiguration();
                config.AddServer("endpoint", 134311);
                config.Protocol = MemcachedProtocol.Binary;
                var mc = new MemcachedClient(config);
                var stat = mc.Store(StoreMode.Set, "Hello", "World");
```

Always false

After local setup I am gettind gerror

Always false

What I am missing

Comment: Are you trying to connect to Aws Memcached from the local machine? You can't do that. Memcached servers can be connected only from another AWS service, such as EC2 machine. From local machine you can not connect to AWS Memcached.

Comment: I have done local setup and found The provided endpoint does not support auto discovery

Comment: I ignored local env and directly testing on server.

Comment: You are running your server on aws?